# How can I give headerTitle to all screens in stackNavigator at once?

Tags: react-native

I have a stackNavigator like

```
const AddAccountStack = createStackNavigator({
  AddAccount: {
    screen: AddAccountScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: () => <HeaderBarIcon/>,
    },
  },
  AddAccountDetail: {
    screen: AddAccountDetailScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: () => <HeaderBarIcon/>,
    },
  },
  AddAccountDone: {
    screen: AddAccountDoneScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: () => <HeaderBarIcon/>,
    },
  }
}, {
  headerLayoutPreset: "center",
});
```

And It works **fine**, **but**, I have to add navigationOptions at all screens. So I want to give navigationOption at once like,

```
const AddAccountStack = createStackNavigator({
  AddAccount: AddAccountScreen,
  AddAccountDetail: AddAccountDetailScreen,
  AddAccountDone: AddAccountDoneScreen,
}, {
  headerLayoutPreset: "center",
  navigationOptions: () => ({
    headerTitle: <HeaderBarIcon/>
  })
});
```

But it doesn't work.

**Could you give me some tips about how I can give `navigationOptions : headerTitle` at stackNavigator at once?**

HeaderBarIcon's code is below,

```
class HeaderBarIcon extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('assets/test.png')}
      style={{ height: "40%" }}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
  );
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const AddAccountStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AddAccount: AddAccountScreen,
    AddAccountDetail: AddAccountDetailScreen,
    AddAccountDone: AddAccountDoneScreen,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: <HeaderBarIcon/>
    }
  }
);
```

Try this out, this should work.
Or change to

```
navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: <HeaderBarIcon/>,
    }),
```

this one is not tested.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work..... I tried exactly the same. Can there be other variables?

Comment: It also didn't work.. I think I set wrong something. Or I use typescript, so It can effect to this. Anyway thanks for answer me.

Answer (score 1):

How about : 
1. Passing the navigation header as hidden from stack navigation.
2. Make a global component of the header.
3. Call that component at every screen.

That would be just one line of code at every screen doing the trick.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the **first** option is not fit for me, because I use back button of header. So I can't set next navigation bar hidden. the **second** option is that I tried, but I failed as you can see in my post. **third** option is working and I use now, But I use more than 20 screens, so it is not clean.

Comment: Make a custom back button and add that. use a common function of goBack in that button and imbed that in your custom header

Comment: Btw all three are not options but they are steps

Comment: I'll consider that. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)